# why Swift type system try to convert a type into wrong expected parameter

Tags: generics, type-systems, swift3, swift-extensions, xcode8

Using Xcode 8 beta, swift 3 the second extension can not compiled. I don't understand if this is a swift bug or a known limitation.

```
extension Array {
    func scanl<T>(initial: T, combine:(Iterator.Element, T) -> T) -> [T] {
        guard let first = self.first else { return [] }
        return [initial] + Array(self.dropFirst()).scanl(initial: combine(first, initial), combine: combine)
    }
}


extension Array {
    func scanl<T>(combine: (Iterator.Element, T) -> T) -> [T] {
        guard let first = self.first else { return [] }
        return Array(self.dropFirst()).scanl(initial:first, combine:combine)// Cannot convert value of type '(Element, T) -> T' To expected argument type '(_, _) -> _'
    }
}
```

(Element, T) -> T is indeed the type of the function.
So i cannot understand why the compiler expect (*,*) -> __ 
and what is this type mean beside "i don't care about the type"

Comment: I'd discourage using recursion here, because it will copy the entire array each call, leading to a time complexity of `O(n^2)`. You're better-off just using a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug or a limitation, it's simply impossible for the compiler to ascertain, at compile-time, that `first` is of type `T` in your second extension (as `T` needn't necessarily be the same as `Iterator.Element`). In both your closures, the compiler knows that `first` is of type `Iterator.Element`, but the compiler cannot know whether this is also type `T`.

In your first extension, you only use `first` as the first argument to the `combine` closure, which expects just the type `Iterator.Element`, so all is good.

In your second extension, however, you attempt to pass `first` as an argument to a parameter (`initial`) which expects type `T`, and the compiler cannot know whether `first` really is of type `T` (the same type `T` as used by the `combine` closure used to call the two-argument `scanl`), namely that `Iterator.Element` of `self` is of type `T`. This can easily be redeemed by an attempted type conversion (`as?`) of `first` to `T` in the optional binding clause of this second extension.

```
extension Array {
    func scanl<T>(combine: (Iterator.Element, T) -> T) -> [T] {
        guard let first = self.first as? T else { return [] }
        return Array(self.dropFirst()).scanl(initial: first, combine: combine)
    }
}
```

The fact that `Iterator.Element` and `T` needn't necessarily be of the same type is apparent if you construct an example that scans an array of one type to construct an array of another type, e.g.

```
/* scant [Int] array to construct [String] array */
let foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let bar = foo.scanl(initial: "0") { String($0) + $1 }
print(bar) // ["0", "10", "210", "3210", "43210"]
```

If you'd only like your `scanl` method and its collector to produce same-type arrays (as the one being scanned), then you needn't include a generic `T`, but could use `Iterator.Element` type in place of `T` in your extensions above.